# Wicket wicket:id inheritance - how to?

Tags: border, wicket

I'm new to wicket an try to understand some examples. One of the examples i try out is the navomatic. The pure example works on my local installation, my next step was to expand it to a Example Application. Therefore i put to a "page" a simple form.

But what i now get is an Exception like:

```
Last cause: Unable to find component with id 'form' in [BorderBodyContainer [Component id = navomaticBorder_body]]
Expected: 'navomaticBorder:bodyBorder:navomaticBorder_body:form'.
Found with similar names: 'form'
```

Here is my code:
NavomaticBorder.java

```
public class NavomaticBorder extends Border {

    public NavomaticBorder(final String id) {
        super(id);
        addToBorder(new MyBorder("navigationBorder"));
        addToBorder(new MyBorder("bodyBorder"));
    }
}
```

NavomaticBorder.html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <wicket:border>
     <div id="main">
       <div id="left_nav">
         <span wicket:id="navigationBorder">
            <wicket:link>
                <a href="MyDataPage.html">My Data</a>
            </wicket:link>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="content_area">
         <span wicket:id="bodyBorder">
            <wicket:body />
         </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </wicket:border>
</body>
</html>
```

MyDataPage.java:

```
public class MyDataPage extends WebPage {

    public MyDataPage() {
        add(new NavomaticBorder("navomaticBorder"));

        // This model references the page's message property and is
        // shared by the label and form component
        final PropertyModel<String> messageModel = new PropertyModel<>(this, "message");

        // The label displays the currently set message
        add(new Label("msg", messageModel));

        // Add a form to change the message. We don't need to do anything
        // else with this form as the shared model is automatically updated
        // on form submits
        final Form<?> form = new Form("form");
        form.add(new TextField("msgInput", messageModel));
        add(form);
    }
}
```

and finally the MyDataPage.html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- <div wicket:id = "mainNavigation"></div> -->
<div wicket:id = "navomaticBorder">
    <div>
        <h3>My Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form wicket:id="form">
            <input type="text" wicket:id="msgInput" value="" size="50" />
            <input type="submit" value="set message" />
        </form>
        <span wicket:id="msg" id="msg">Message goes here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess it is a inheritence problem, but i'm not sure how to resolve it.
Can anyone give me a hint to a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You placed the form inside of the novomaticBorder but didn't add it in your component hierarchy.

Wicket Code:

- navomaticBorder
- msg
- form

Markup:

- navomaticBorder

  - form
  - msg

You have to add the form to your border.

```
    NavomaticBorder navomaticBorder = new NavomaticBorder("navomaticBorder")
    add(navomaticBorder);

    //...

    navomaticBorder.add(form);
```

Alternativly you can queue the components instead of add them:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/componentQueueing.html
The queuing will autoresolve the hierarchy in the markup

```
    queue(new NavomaticBorder("navomaticBorder"));
    //...
    queue(form);
```

Comment: Hi, yeahhh, that was the problem. It so simple and clear that i have just to add the component to the Border component. Thanks very much!